# SQL - returning two matching values

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, case

The query below returns the info I need; two columns the being the status number, the second being the total number.

```
SELECT T.number as 'Number',T.total as 'highest service level'
 FROM(
   SELECT PARTNER_WORKORDER.statusNo as number, count(statusNo) as total
   FROM PARTNER_WORKORDER
     inner join PARTNER_WORKORDER_ADDRESS
   ON PARTNER_WORKORDER.salesOrderNo = PARTNER_WORKORDER_ADDRESS.salesorder_no
   WHERE orderDt <= '2012-11-20 00:00:00.000' AND country_code <> 'US'
   group by PARTNER_WORKORDER.statusNo
 )
AS T
```

What I need to do now is return JUST the highest total and the status number that matches it. I know MAX will give me the highest total, but I have no idea how to get the status number that matches that total. I think I need to use CASE, but I've never had any experience with that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you just looking to return a single record? or do want the max record for each `Number`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `order by` and `limit` or `top` or `fetch first 1 row only`.  For example:

```
SELECT PARTNER_WORKORDER.statusNo as number, count(statusNo) as total
FROM PARTNER_WORKORDER inner join
     PARTNER_WORKORDER_ADDRESS
     ON PARTNER_WORKORDER.salesOrderNo = PARTNER_WORKORDER_ADDRESS.salesorder_no
WHERE orderDt <= '2012-11-20 00:00:00.000' AND country_code <> 'US'
group by PARTNER_WORKORDER.statusNo
ORDER BY total desc
LIMIT 1
```

Note that you don't need the subquery for this.  The SQL Standard would be `fetch first 1 rows only` instead of `limit 1`, but not that many databases support that (yet).

Comment: I changed it to SELECT TOP 1 PARTNER_.... for the select row and it works perfectly now.  Not sure if that is because I am using Microsoft SQLServer or not, but your reply got me to the right answer.  Much thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is because you are using SQL Server.  SQL Server, Sybase, Teradata, and MS Access use `TOP`; Postgres and MySQL use `LIMIT`; Oracle uses `rownum`; DB2, Oracle, and SQL Server use `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY`.  The latter is standard, but only the most recent versions of Oracle and SQL Server support it.